# Finetuning Cifar data with VGG net

Tags: computer-vision, caffe, vgg-net

The original VGG network accepts input of size 256x256x3. In order to train Cifar-10 data, do I need to resize the data into 256x256x3? Or is there any other way?

I am trying to fine tune VGG network using Cifar-10 data, which is of size 32x32x3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to train the Cifar-10 data on VGG, you will have to give input data of size 256x256x3. Various input layers have transform parameters to take care of this image resizing.

But upscaling a 32x32 image to 256x256 is not a good method as a major portion of the image data is created by an approximation from the available 32x32 image data. So I do not recommend doing this. But if this is just to try a demo VGG finetuning, you could do it by setting the transform parameter.

Comment: Thanks. If it is not a good idea to upscale 32x32 image, then what other alternatives can I try?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the reduced version of VGG for smaller images since VGG-16 is too complex for small images.

I think this model works better for your problem and it's not hard to train it all with a gpu:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same',
                 input_shape=x_train.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```